# v2 python programming model and Azure Functions: dynamic amount of blob_output bindings

Tags: python, azure-functions

I'm creating an Azure Function that will receive an array of images URLs and should download them all on Blob storage. I'm using the new v2 programming model with decorators. Here is the dummy code to illustrate:

```
import azure.functions as func
import datetime
import json
import logging
from pathlib import Path
import urllib
import uuid

app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.route(route="MyHttpTrigger", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)
@app.blob_output(arg_name="outputblob",
                path="newblob/folder",
                connection="AzureWebJobsStorage")
def MyHttpTrigger(req: func.HttpRequest, outputblob: func.Out[str]) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    images = [
        {
            "url": "https://.../dodgenc_dodgenc16juldji0001(466).jpg",
            "filename": "file1.jpg",
            "size": 12345,
        },
        {
            "url": "https://.../greenwood_img00112.jpg",
            "filename": "file2.jpg",
            "size": 12345,
        },
    ]

    for img in images:
        img_extension = Path(img['filename']).suffix
        local_path = Path('folder/'+str(uuid.uuid4()) + img_extension)
        try:
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(img['url'], local_path)
            logging.info(f"Downloading {img['url']} to {local_path}")

            # Upload data from local to blob storage.
            logging.warning(f"Uploading {local_path} to {outputblob}")
            outputblob.set(local_path.read_bytes())
        except Exception as e:
            logging.warning(f"Could not fetch image {img.url}. Exception: \n{e}")

    return func.HttpResponse(
            "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.",
            status_code=200
    )
```

This code works fine except that there are two images written to the same blob, so the second one overwrites the first one. I could work around that by introducing a second `blob_output`, one for each image. But how to do if **I don't know in advance** how many images to process?

Is there a way to dynamically set the number of output bindings (I expect not)? Alternatively, how could I download all the images to a folder in blob storage?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> I'm creating an Azure Function that will receive an array of images URLs and should download them all on Blob storage

I have created http trigger function with run time stack python.

I have done some changes in your function code and then I am able to get two images got downloaded and uploaded into azure storage account container.
Below code is works fine.

**Function code:**

```
import azure.functions as func
import logging
from pathlib import Path
import urllib
import uuid

app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.route(route="MyHttpTrigger", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)
@app.blob_output(arg_name="outputblob1",
                path="pavan/hellooo1.jpg",  # Change the path for the first image
                connection="AzureWebJobsStorage")
@app.blob_output(arg_name="outputblob2",
                path="pavan/hellooo2.jpg",  # Change the path for the second image
                connection="AzureWebJobsStorage")
def MyHttpTrigger(req: func.HttpRequest, outputblob1: func.Out[bytes], outputblob2: func.Out[bytes]) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    images = [
        {
            "url": "Your-first-image URL",
            "filename": "file1.jpg",
            "size": 12345,
        },
        {
            "url": "your-second-image URL",
            "filename": "file2.jpg",
            "size": 12345,
        },
    ]

    for img in images:
        img_extension = Path(img['filename']).suffix
        local_path = Path('folder1') / (str(uuid.uuid4()) + img_extension)  # Use different folder for the first image
        try:
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(img['url'], local_path)
            logging.info(f"Downloading {img['url']} to {local_path}")

            # Upload data from local to blob storage.
            with open(local_path, "rb") as file:
                outputblob1.set(file.read())

            logging.warning(f"Uploaded {local_path} to {outputblob1}")
        except Exception as e:
            logging.warning(f"Could not fetch image {img['url']}. Exception: \n{e}")

    # Repeat the process for the second image
    for img in images:
        img_extension = Path(img['filename']).suffix
        local_path = Path('folder2') / (str(uuid.uuid4()) + img_extension)  # Use different folder for the second image
        try:
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(img['url'], local_path)
            logging.info(f"Downloading {img['url']} to {local_path}")

            # Upload data from local to blob storage.
            with open(local_path, "rb") as file:
                outputblob2.set(file.read())

            logging.warning(f"Uploaded {local_path} to {outputblob2}")
        except Exception as e:
            logging.warning(f"Could not fetch image {img['url']}. Exception: \n{e}")

    return func.HttpResponse(
        "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.",
        status_code=200
    )
```

The above code executed successfully. check below:

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Yes but it doesn't address how to deal with an unknown-in-advance amount of images